# The candidate with the bigger campain budget is allways elected

Tags: united-states, politics

Hearing a french conference, the speaker told us that it's easy to understand american presidential elections, because the candidate with the highest campain budget allways is choosen.

But I can't find actual datas, and I wonder if it is true.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you mean by "campaign budget."  If by that you mean how much a campaign *spent*, then *no*: The candidate who spent the most money (or for whom the most money was spent on their behalf) does *not* always win the election.  The prime counterexample was the 2012 Obama/Romney election, in which [Romney out-spent Obama by over $6 million](http://elections.nytimes.com/2012/campaign-finance) and still lost.  However, the Obama campaign had raised over $80 million *more* than the Romney campaign; they just chose not to spend as much.

In the 2014 elections, there were a number of hotly contested congressional races in which the winner both raised and spent less money (*e.g.*, [Georgia senate](https://www.opensecrets.org/races/summary.php?id=GAS1&cycle=2014), [Colorado senate](https://www.opensecrets.org/races/summary.php?id=COS2&cycle=2014), [California house of representatives](https://www.opensecrets.org/races/summary.php?id=CA07&cycle=2014), [New York house of representatives](https://www.opensecrets.org/races/summary.php?id=NY19&cycle=2014), *&c.*).

So, these counterexamples prove that the candidate who raises or spends more money does not necessarily win the election.  Whether or not the candidate who raises/spends more money is statistically *more likely* to win is a different question that may in fact be true.